# Code modified in BSP application did not reflect in SAP FIORI. How to fix?

Tags: sap-fiori

I synced our BSP application in Eclipse and removed a table cell control which did not reflect in my Fiori application.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a component-preload file, it's possible it needs to be rebuilt to contain the new code, or you may need to run /ui5/app_index_calculate

Comment: It works after component-preload is modified. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulCalvin Please do not modify Component-preload.js directly. It will be overwritten by the next build of the application.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice deploy your app throught T-CODE se38 ---> program /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORYLOAD

Here insert your UI5 Application name and choose Download, do your modifies, then in the same transaction(se38) same program (/UI5_UI5_REPOSITORYLOAD) insert the same UI5 Application name and choose Upload. Finally test the app